# Customized button text for file upload

Tags: asp.net, htmlcontrols

How do I change the button text of file upload HTML control from default "Browse" to anyother text?

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy solution, but this site:

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom

provides you with a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It depends on browser/OS. I should clarify: you can't change the text of the button directly, but there are some workarounds (as Erik [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092155/customized-button-text-for-file-upload/2092167#2092167))